# CloudFront HLS streaming not working - S3 (HLS v4)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, html5-video

I setup a S3 based HLS streaming using CloudFront, but the HLS streaming doesn't seem to work. I have a created the bucket and transcoded content using this webcast:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuQ_qg7U0l8

The content seems to have the right permissions, but mime types are missing (I see m3u8 to have mime type text/plain. Shouldnt' transcoder set this correctly?

I'm not sure if this is the reason the video doesn't play. In Chrome, it just shows a blank screen using HTML5  tag, and in Safari if i try to play it directly, it shows the play button but nothing else.

Any ideas where to look? My original content was mp4 (before using elastic transcoder)

UPDATE: Ahh seems to be a problem with HLS-v4, works fine if I transcode to HLS-v3. So perhaps not related to mime-type (same mimetypes in v3)

Comment: Do you have a test URL?

Comment: Test url: http://dza0asocajni2.cloudfront.net/master.m3u8
@aergistal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your test stream and the mime types are correct:

```
curl -I http://.../master.m3u8
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-mpegURL

curl -I http://.../hls_1m_.ts
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: video/MP2T
```

The stream also plays correctly.

Some clients only support the **version 3** of the protocol and I think this is your issue.

**Version 4** added byte-range support through `EXT-X-BYTERANGE`. See your playlist:

```
#EXTINF:3.754688999999999,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:118258@1990168
hls_1m_.ts
```

This will definitely cause issues with some players which don't support the new features. The safest way is to go with **version 3** for now.

Comment: duh, for some reason it just started working on Safari too, I'm stumped! Thanks aergistal for looking!

Comment: Safari might support it since it's made by Apple which also made HLS

Comment: yes i now, but if you read my question again, it didn't work earlier in Safari either!

Comment: How to check the MIME type

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using s3 public bucket, and was not able to stream,

I tried setting the  CORS configuration  in s3 and it worked fine

I added the following in S3 console  CORS configuration( s3 > "public bucket" > permissions > CORS configuration)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
 <CORSRule>
     <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
     <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
     <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
 </CORSRule>
 </CORSConfiguration>
```

for more details [this](https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/tutorials/create/beginner/s3-video/) might help you